# C# Merging classes at run time; is MEF a good candidate

Tags: c#

I have the following situation:

A common lib, "LibA", with default settings. The default settings are implemented through an abstract class, "SettingsA".
These settings are used in LibA.

Each app that uses LibA has to implement a class that derives from the SettingsA and override whatever they want to change.

In LibA, there is a singleton class that finds the derived class and returns settings from it, so LibA has access to the overridden settings.

So far, it works very well..

Now, I have LibB; LibB also has the same settings mechanism and depends on LibA.

Apps that use LibA and LibB.

I am wondering if thre is a way I could implement something where:
Each app is able to create classes that derive from SettingsA and SettingsB and then I could have a mechanism that 'groups' SettingsA and SettingsB under the same API.

Essentially it would behave as if the app would build a global dictionary with SettingsA, SettingsB and overriding entries based on the apps' settings.

I don't want to use a dictionary since suddenly we can't use auto-complete and people will start to misspell names, etc.

I was looking at MEF as a way to 'import' several classes into one.
But, does it make sense to go that route?

A dynamic doesn't make sense since it would essentially behave like a dictionary as well.

Comment: Why is "SettingsA" an abstract class and not an interface?

Comment: Why would auto-complete break if you use a Dictionary?

Comment: @progman: because the default implementation has a lot of settings that do not need to be modified; I expect an app to maybe change 20-25% of the value and keep the rest default

Comment: @Kenneth: when querying the values, the key has to be entered manually; there is no autocomplete for MyDict["ConnectionString"] for example; currently people access this way: Settings.Data.ConnectionString (the Data field is the instance from the singleton); and there is no type issue as well this way.

Comment: It sounds like by "auto-complete" you really mean Intellisense. If so, how do you expect this to be a runtime feature? Intellisense is design-time.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant intellisense; since the values are known in the settings classes, intellisense picks them right now; I know it could be solved easily with a dictionary, but that's what I'm trying to avoid; typing would also be an issue as I'd have to make all parameters an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like the Decorator pattern, but with two fields referencing the different setting base classes.

```
public abstract class MergeSettingsBase : ISettingsA, ISettingsB
{
    private readonly ISettingsA _settingsA;
    private readonly ISettingsB _settingsB;

    public MergeSettingsBase(ISettingsA settingsA, ISettingsB settingsB)
    {
        _settingsA = settingsA;
        _settingsB = settingsB;
    }

    string ISettingsA.SomeValue {
        get {
            return _settingsA.SomeValue;
        }
    }

    int ISettingsB.AnotherValue {
        get {
            return _settingsB.AnotherValue;
        }
    }
}

public class Settings : MergeSettingsBase {
    override string ISettingsA.SomeValue {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

Comment: But this would require SettingsA and SettingsB to be interfaces, right? The author is saying both are abstract classes..

Comment: I thought about that too but I don't remember the rationale behind us not going for interfaces (we're talking about a code base with a bunch of history behind it).
Somehow I'd like that accessing the class would be like both classes are one; the dynamic type would solve it, but we'd lose intellisense; and with a dictionnary we'd lose intellisense as well and complicate types